# How to use crosstab or pivote in mysql query to get month names dynamicaly?

Tags: mysql

I have table named user_plan_dtl with the columns userid, plan description and contact date. I want count of users in each month according to plan description. And month should get selected only within a given date range.
I have database in mysql.

Below is the table user_plan_dtl

```
userid        contactdate  plandesc
USR001           March       ICMA
USR003           March       ICMA
USR004           April       FTDA
USR005           April       FTDA
USR006           April       FTDA
USR007           April       ICMA
USR008           April       ICMA
USR009           May         FTDA
USR002           May         FTDA
USR001           May         ICMA
```

I want output like :

```
 Count    March  April  May
 Total     2      5      3
 FTDA      0      3      2
 ICMA      2      2      1
```

I have tried with below query but I am getting output for all the months.

```
select  d.Plandesc as AssignedUsers, max(d.January) as January,max(d.February) as February,max(d.March) as March,
max(d.April) as April ,max(d.May)as May,max(d.June)as June,
max(d.July) as July,max(d.August)as August,max(d.September) as September,
max(d.October)as October,max(d.November) as November ,max(d.December)as December from
(Select Plandesc,  
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='January' THEN userid END )) AS January,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='February' THEN userid END )) AS February,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='March' THEN userid END )) AS March,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='April' THEN userid END )) AS April,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='May' THEN userid END )) AS May,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='June' THEN userid END )) AS June,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='July' THEN userid END )) AS July,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='August' THEN userid END )) AS August,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='September' THEN userid END )) AS September,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='October' THEN userid END )) AS October,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='November' THEN userid END )) AS November,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='December' THEN userid END )) AS December
from user_plan_dtl 
where Plandesc in ('FTDA','ICMA')   
and DATE_FORMAT(contactdate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-01-01' and DATE_FORMAT(contactdate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-07-05'
group by  MONTHNAME(contactdate),Plandesc
union all
Select 'Total' as Plandesc,  
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='January' THEN userid END )) AS January,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='February' THEN userid END )) AS February,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='March' THEN userid END )) AS March,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='April' THEN userid END )) AS April,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='May' THEN userid END )) AS May,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='June' THEN userid END )) AS June,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='July' THEN userid END )) AS July,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='August' THEN userid END )) AS August,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='September' THEN userid END )) AS September,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='October' THEN userid END )) AS October,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='November' THEN userid END )) AS November,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)='December' THEN userid END )) AS December
from user_plan_dtl 
where Plandesc in ('FTDA','ICMA')   
and DATE_FORMAT(contactdate, '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2017-01-01' and DATE_FORMAT(contactdate, '%Y-%m-%d') <= '2017-07-05'
group by  MONTHNAME(contactdate)
) as d group by d.Plandesc order by case when d.Plandesc = 'Total' then 0 else 1 end,d.Plandesc
```

Can anyone plaese provide me the solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution, setting variables and using prepared statements:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_plan_temp;

SET @JanTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='January' );
SET @FebTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='February');
SET @MarTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='March');
SET @AprTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='April');
SET @MayTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='May');
SET @JunTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='June');
SET @JulTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='July');
SET @AugTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='August');
SET @SepTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='September');
SET @OctTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='October');
SET @NovTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='November');
SET @DecTotal = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc IN ('FTDA','ICMA') AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='December');

SET @SQLq = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE user_plan_temp AS (SELECT "Total" AS Count '; 
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@JanTotal > 0, ', @JanTotal AS January',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@FebTotal > 0, ', @FebTotal AS February',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@MarTotal > 0, ', @MarTotal AS March',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@AprTotal > 0, ', @AprTotal AS April',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@MayTotal > 0, ', @MayTotal AS May',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@JunTotal > 0, ', @JunTotal AS June',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@JulTotal > 0, ', @JulTotal AS July',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@AugTotal > 0, ', @AugTotal AS August',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@SepTotal > 0, ', @SepTotal AS September',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@OctTotal > 0, ', @OctTotal AS October',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@NovTotal > 0, ', @NovTotal AS November',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, IF(@DecTotal > 0, ', @DecTotal AS December',''));
SET @SQLq = CONCAT(@SQLq, ')');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQLq; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
-- SELECT * FROM user_plan_temp;

SET @SQLq2 = 'INSERT INTO user_plan_temp VALUES("FTDA" '; 
SET @JanFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='January' );
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@JanTotal > 0, ', @JanFTDA',''));
SET @FebFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='February');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@FebTotal > 0, ', @FebFTDA',''));
SET @MarFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='March');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@MarTotal > 0, ', @MarFTDA',''));
SET @AprFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='April');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@AprTotal > 0, ', @AprFTDA',''));
SET @MayFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='May');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@MayTotal > 0, ', @MayFTDA',''));
SET @JunFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='June');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@JunTotal > 0, ', @JunFTDA',''));
SET @JulFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='July');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@JulTotal > 0, ', @JulFTDA',''));
SET @AugFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='August');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@AugTotal > 0, ', @AugFTDA',''));
SET @SepFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='September');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@SepTotal > 0, ', @SepFTDA',''));
SET @OctFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='October');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@OctTotal > 0, ', @OctFTDA',''));
SET @NovFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='November');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@NovTotal > 0, ', @NovFTDA',''));
SET @DecFTDA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'FTDA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='December');
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, IF(@DecTotal > 0, ', @DecFTDA',''));
SET @SQLq2 = CONCAT(@SQLq2, ')');
-- SELECT @SQLq2;
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @SQLq2; 
EXECUTE stmt2; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2; 

SET @SQLq3 = 'INSERT INTO user_plan_temp VALUES("FTDA" '; 
SET @JanICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='January' );
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@JanTotal > 0, ', @JanICMA',''));
SET @FebICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='February');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@FebTotal > 0, ', @FebICMA',''));
SET @MarICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='March');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@MarTotal > 0, ', @MarICMA',''));
SET @AprICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='April');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@AprTotal > 0, ', @AprICMA',''));
SET @MayICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='May');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@MayTotal > 0, ', @MayICMA',''));
SET @JunICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='June');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@JunTotal > 0, ', @JunICMA',''));
SET @JulICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='July');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@JulTotal > 0, ', @JulICMA',''));
SET @AugICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='August');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@AugTotal > 0, ', @AugICMA',''));
SET @SepICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='September');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@SepTotal > 0, ', @SepICMA',''));
SET @OctICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='October');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@OctTotal > 0, ', @OctICMA',''));
SET @NovICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='November');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@NovTotal > 0, ', @NovICMA',''));
SET @DecICMA = (Select COUNT(DISTINCT(userid)) from user_plan_dtl WHERE plandesc = 'ICMA' AND MONTHNAME(contactdate)='December');
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, IF(@DecTotal > 0, ', @DecICMA',''));
SET @SQLq3 = CONCAT(@SQLq3, ')');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @SQLq3; 
EXECUTE stmt3; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3; 

SELECT * FROM user_plan_temp;
```

Comment: Thank You So Much TBowman,Thanks a lot... This solution is working perfect.... Only the change i have done is,  in SET @SQLq3 = 'INSERT INTO user_plan_temp VALUES("FTDA" ';  ....... instead of FTDA it should be ICMA, because we are inserting values for ICMA. Anyways you saved my lot of time, thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT` to construct complex queries.

```
set @sql=NULL;
select group_concat(distinct concat(
  ' COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)="',c_month,
     '" THEN userid END )) AS "',c_month,'"') separator ',') 
  from (select distinct contactdate as c_month from user_plan_dtl) t into @sql;
select @sql;
```

(note that I've used `contactdate` from the data you posted here as a month, not as a date)

This will give you a string in the variable `@sql`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)="March" THEN userid END ))
    AS "March",
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)="April" THEN userid END ))
    AS "April",
COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(contactdate)="May" THEN userid END ))
    AS "May"
```

Then you can manipulate this string

```
set @sql=concat('SELECT ',@sql);
select @sql;
```

and so on. (hint: create another variable for the whole statement and concatenate it with `@sql`). Finally you have to prepare and execute this sql statement:

```
PREPARE stmnt from @sql;
EXECUTE stmnt;
DEALLOCATE stmnt;
```

Comment: Hey Michael..thanks for your comment, but here you have used March , April and May hard coded. I want this dynamically.

Comment: They are not "hardcoded", they are from your table, just use `select distinct monthname(contactdate) as c_month`. Have you even read the answer?

Comment: Oh sorry... now i got the answer and I think this would be faster than above one, But i am not getting the hint mentioned by you .... (hint: create another variable for the whole statement and concatenate it with @sql), can you please elaborate it more,please.

Comment: Well, since these COUNTs would be used in two places, it would be better to use this one variable for this. Also you have to create a variable in similar way for max's in your query.